# I accidentally deleted the MySQL socket file ('/tmp/mysql.sock') permanently ,how can i fix it?

Tags: mysql, database, sockets

After that, I reinstalled mysql, but still got: `Can't connect to Error: local MySQL server through socket'/tmp/mysql.sock'(2)`.

Tried to start the server: `start mysql.server`, but got:

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/appledeMacBook-Pro-6.local.pid).
```

The next thing I tried was:

```
mysqladmin -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p shutdown
```

and got:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at '127.0.0.1' failed
error: 'Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)'
Check that mysqld is running on 127.0.0.1 and that the port is 3306.
You can check this by doing 'telnet 127.0.0.1 3306'
```

I followed this tip (telnet 127.0.0.1 3306) and got:

```
connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Deleting the `.err` file should solve this problem.

Comment: after i reinstalled ,there wasn't any *.err in usr/local/var/mysql

Answer (score 1):

- `ps aux | grep mysql`
- `sudo kill -9 [PID]`
- `sudo mysql.server start`

Comment: thx for answer ,i have been tried this way before  asked, i found this process's stat is S+ or R+(it's all backstage process ,and could not killed even use other instructions like: pkill -9 mysql )

Answer (score 0):

I hope you tried restarting your machine and I hope you give mysql correct permission to write.